# How to get the ProcessInstance for a workflow item?

Tags: core-service, workflow

How can I get the ProcessData object from a workflow item using the core service?  The code below gets the LinkToProcessInstanceData but not the actual ProcessInstance.

Is there a way to convert from a LinkToProcessInstanceData to ProcessData?

```
LinkToProcessInstanceData procInstanceLinkData = wfItem.WorkflowInfo.ProcessInstance;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way is called `Read`:

```
var processInstance = (ProcessInstanceData) client.Read(wfItem.WorkflowInfo.ProcessInstance.IdRef, new ReadOptions());
```

Comment: Aha!  I'm too used to the old TOM.NET way of everything being an object or method off of the main object and didn't think to call .Read.  I keep forgetting that we're really dealing with a pile of XML under these calls and the appearance of a real API is only that, an appearance...

Comment: It is a real API, just a Service-on-top-of-data one instead of the typical OO stuff we're used to. Much lighter of the wire too, TOM is particularly chatty and DB heavy

Comment: I agree that is is lighter weight and performs better in many cases.  Sometimes I miss the whole OO goodness though....